# Only initialize a variable in an array if it's requested

Tags: php, arrays, lazy-loading

Here's a little mock-up to describe my predicament:

```
<?php
$var = "Before";

function getVar(){
    global $var;

    return $var;
}

$array = Array(
    "variable" => "Var = " . getVar()
);

$var = "After";

echo $array['variable'];
?>
```

That code would echo 'Before', I'm aiming for it to echo 'after'. I realize that this is how PHP is *supposed* to work however it's crucial for the array to execute `getVar()` only when it's called.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This code would not echo `Before`, as `$var` is out of `getVar`'s scope. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @JohnV. -  No, the question is clear. However, it's not something that could be achieved with 'native' way

Comment: I think I might understand it now after re-reading the question, maybe [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) is what they're looking for.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to go for OOP and magic methods.

Comment: You are talking about lazy-loading. Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading. There is even example in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this since array declaration *will initialize it* - so you're mixing function calling at array's 'usage' and at it's definition. There's no 'usage': array is *already defined* to that moment.

However, an answer could be using [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), like this:

```
class XArray implements ArrayAccess
{
   private $storage = [];

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->storage = func_get_args();
   }

   public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
   {
      if(is_null($offset)) 
      {
         $this->storage[] = $value;
      } 
      else
      {
         $this->storage[$offset] = $value;
      }
   }

   public function offsetExists($offset) 
   {
      return isset($this->storage[$offset]);
   }

   public function offsetUnset($offset) 
   {
      unset($this->storage[$offset]);
   }

   public function offsetGet($offset) 
   {
      if(!isset($this->storage[$offset]))
      {
         return null;
      }
      return is_callable($this->storage[$offset])?
             call_user_func($this->storage[$offset]):
             $this->storage[$offset];
   }
}

function getVar()
{
   global $var;
   return $var;
}

$var = 'Before Init';
$array = new XArray('foo', 'getVar', 'bar');
$var = 'After Init';
var_dump($array[1]);//'After Init'
```

-i.e. try to call data, which is inside element, when actual get happened. You may want to have different constructor (for associative arrays) - but the general idea was shown.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer after the question was edited.

No, what you are trying to achieve isn't possible because when you call the function it returns and it's done at that point. But you could achieve something similar with object oriented coding. I'll create something for you, please wait.

```
<?php

class Foo {

  public function __toString() {
    global $var;
    return "Var = {$var}";
  }

}

$var = "Before";

$array = array( "variable" => new Foo() );

$var = "After";

echo $array['variable'];

?>
```

PS: Sorry for the late answer, but there was a blackout in Salzburg. :(

Comment: It's not the answer (or may be not the one that will fit OP's request) since it's not 'access for array item' - but calling it

Comment: Sorry about that, after a few hours of coding my mind is kind of mush right now. I should have probably specified that I'm intending to mix strings with the key's value, eg `"variable" => "Var = " . getVar()`

Comment: Concur. An object implementing array access instead of a primitive array would facilitate this.

Comment: @phil-lavin Could you expand on that?

Comment: The edited answer suggests @Fleshgrinder is on the case producing an example for you. If not, I'll knock something up quickly.

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo's answer is what I was eluding to

Comment: Finally was able to provide my idea, there was a blackout here in Salzburg and I had no WWW access.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that you could also use *anonymous* functions and invoke/execute those

**Proof of concept:**

```
$var = "Before";

function getVar(){
    global $var;

    return $var;
}

$array = Array(
    "variable" => create_function(null, "return 'Var = ' . getVar();")
);

$var = "After";

echo $array['variable']();
```

returns

```
Var = After
```

[image]